# how to get pod to pod ping on different nodes working?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I would like to be able to ping from one pod to another. That works if the pods are on the same host. It does not work if the pods are on different hosts.

```
$ kubectl get pod,svc -o wide
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP                NODE                  NOMINATED NODE
pod/bbtest-5949c4d8c5-259wx   1/1       Running   1          2d        192.168.114.158   gordon-dm1.sdsc.edu   <none>
pod/busybox-7cd98849ff-m75qv   0/1      Running   0          3m        192.168.78.30     gordon-dm3.sdsc.edu   <none>pod/nginx-64f497f8fd-j4qml    1/1       Running   0          20m       192.168.114.163   gordon-dm1.sdsc.edu   <none>
pod/nginx-64f497f8fd-tw4vb    1/1       Running   0          22m       192.168.209.32    gordon-dm4.sdsc.edu   <none>

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE       SELECTOR
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   17d       <none>
```

```
$ kubectl run busybox --rm -ti --image busybox /bin/sh
/ # ping 192.168.114.163
PING 192.168.114.163 (192.168.114.163): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.114.163 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
/ #
```

I set up flannel but it doesn't make a change. I tried felixconfiguration only to get an error : resource does not exist: FelixConfiguration(default)

Any help to get pod to pod communication to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use a `service` and open the nginx specific ports that require to receive connections and use the service hostname.

Use `curl -I <service-name>.<namespace>` for testing.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

Result:

```
/ # curl -I my-nginx.default
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.19.6
Date: Sun, 03 Jan 2021 17:44:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Dec 2020 13:59:38 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5fd8c14a-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

*P.S. I used `kubectl run alpine --rm -ti --image alpine /bin/sh` and `apk add curl`*